# In servlet (web app) how do I know the relative path?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a jsp file in the root of .war file.
and then I have a folder named STUFF.

How do I get access to the file read.txt inside STUFF?

/Name_of_war/STUFF/read.txt is the correct path?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The webapp-relative path is `/STUFF/read.txt`.

You *could* use [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to convert a relative web path to an absolute local disk file system path. This way you can use it further in the usual `java.io` stuff which actually knows nothing about the web context it is running in. E.g.

```
String relativeWebPath = "/STUFF/read.txt";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
// Do your thing with File.
```

This however doesn't work if the server is configured to expand the WAR in memory instead of on disk. Using `getRealPath()` has always this caveat and is not recommended in real world applications. If all you ultimately need is just getting an `InputStream` of that file, for which you would likely have used `FileInputStream`, you'd better use [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get it directly as `InputStream`:

```
String relativeWebPath = "/STUFF/read.txt";
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(relativeWebPath);
// Do your thing with InputStream.
```

Comment: I wasted one day trying and trying.. faced `FileNotFoundException` and it's working in local but not in web. got frustrated.. but finally i come across your answer and tried.. it works awesome.. Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is located in the classpath, or you can add the folder to the classpath,
How about:
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);