# GoogleCredential client API is not able to find File path in web application

Tags: java, file, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar client API and trying to authenticate with Google.
 **Following code is working in standalone application and not working in web application environment**.
 In case of web application,
 `setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(File)` method is not able to find the path what i provided, I tried in many ways of answers given by stackexchange users.
 But for me no use.Everytime it is showing only one message, File path (no such file or path).
  Don't know what's wrong. Please help me to find a solution to this problem.

```
GoogleCredential credential =   new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)  
.setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY) 
.setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
.setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))  
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(CLIENT_SECRET)).build();
```

Here the `private static final String CLIENT_SECRET="credentials/Test.p12"`;
I tried with `ClassLoaders`,`URL` but no use. always throwing the `FileNotFoundException`.
My project is **maven** project and the code is in **dependent jar file.**

Comment: Is your path correct and exist?

Comment: Of course, since it is a maven project, in resources folder i have created credentials folder and put that file.

Comment: Since you are using a relative path is that correctly map to the folder that you mention?

Comment: Yes. I have created folder in right place,i.e resources folder and this code is made as jar file and which is dependent file to web application. so is it the problem unbale to locate the file ?

Comment: Most probably the relative path is nor correctly specify.Read on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455474/in-servlet-web-app-how-do-i-know-the-relative-path

Comment: I didn't mention absolute path in the standalone application,but how there it identified by FIle ? why not the same thing in web context ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61553/discussion-between-mr-chowdary-and-thusitha-thilina-dayaratne).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the problem with Google Client API.
In web application, we should give **absolute path** to create a **File** instance.
Generally web application gives relative path, it is not possible to create **File** instace with this relative path in Java.
Because `java.io.File` doesn't know about relative paths. it knows only OS specific absolute paths to create instance of **File**
so for that,`String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/credentials/secret.p12");`
This is working as expected.
Thanks for help in comments.